# How to remove my application name from the URL?

Tags: java, glassfish

When I go into my Glassfish admin panel I go to Applications and I see my application listed (named `cmt`).  When I click Launch it opens a tab with some URLs.  There are a few issues with these URLs I'm struggling to find answers for on how to fix.

1. I only want HTTPS, not http.  Is this controller on the server or application level?
2. These URLs have `/cmt` on the end of the domain name.  I really need the user to access my application on the base url without having a `/cmt` on the end.  How can I control this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to your first question, if you want to *require* SSL connections to your web application then you are going to have to do some additional server configuration. I will refer you to [this](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/) tutorial.

For your second question, change your web.xml and set its context root to `/`:

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

Comment: I actually changed the context root it through my Netbeans application properties, thanks!